# why in IYPT problem it said that the non-ferromagnetic disk repel?!how?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

for the shaded-pole motor, our rotatable disk is paramagnetic, so it must be attracted to the magnetic field of the inductor. but in the question it said it repelled.
does that para disk increase the ***B*** and because of this it will be repelled by the Lenz's law?!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the magnetic field were static then the paramagnetic copper disk would indeed be attracted into it. However an oscillating magnetic field will generally repel conducting materials. This is because the oscillating field induces eddy currents in the conductor and the eddy currents in turn generate a magnetic field that repels the original field.

This process is the basis of [magnetic levitation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation). See in particular the section of this article on [oscillating fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Oscillating_electromagnetic_fields).

Comment: ok but how?!why the aluminum disk that is paramagnetic,repels in the magnetic field of AC current?!?!

Comment: Did you read the article on magnetic levitation that I linked? That explains the underlying physics. You might also be interested in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142732/how-does-hendo-hoverboards-achieve-the-self-propelling-motion-what-is-the-mfa) because it also involves repulsion due to oscillating magnetic fields.