# How does the hendo hoverboard achieve omni-directional movement?

Tags: electromagnetism, levitation

An older thread already gave away the wonderful details of how the Hendo hoverboard achieves levitation, but how does it achieve its form of omni-directional control and movement?

My idea was that each engine had a gyro or gimballed mount that fed to it's artificial feedback system, and would change its pitch in response to user command, but the engines looked a bit thin to be able to hold these systems. Another concept was the use of electromagnets with varying fields, mounted throughout the board's frame.

However, I still do not understand how the boards able to create propulsion with only four engines, and what appears to be no kind of stabilizers or thrusters.

Comment: I'm on mobile at the moment so I cannot search, but I am fairly certain that this had been asked & answered previously.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142732/2451

Comment: I was in a similar thread, but that had to do with how it generated lift, not how about controlled itself. I might do more looking around.

Answer (score 0):

Put 2 wheels on it. Power them with electric motors. Add tap comand with feet to donte speed variance. It would probably need both rear and front magnetic breaking systems that work independently. It should also be able to move as if you were looking straight forwad this is balance controlled it would need to know how fast to make the wheels go to to catch up to your forward momentum also.